# How to set the base URI for an XSLT script?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Is there a way to set the base URI in XSLT so it applies for the whole document like in XQuery?

I.e.

```
declare base-uri = "someuri";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not possible to change the base URI of a document**. From the **[XML Base W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlbase/#granularity)**.:

> "The base URI of a document entity or
>   an external entity is determined by
>   RFC 3986 rules, namely, that the base
>   URI is the URI used to retrieve the
>   document entity or external entity."

The base URI of any *node* in the document (with the exception of the `document-node()`) *can* be set using `xml:base` (again **[there](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlbase/#syntax)**)

> "The attribute xml:base may be
>   inserted in XML documents to specify a
>   base URI other than the base URI of
>   the document or external entity"

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document

> The URI reference may be relative. The
>   base URI (see [3.2 Base URI]) of the
>   node in the second argument node-set
>   that is first in document order is
>   used as the base URI for resolving the
>   relative URI into an absolute URI. If
>   the second argument is omitted, then
>   it defaults to the node in the
>   stylesheet that contains the
>   expression that includes the call to
>   the document function.

And from http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#base-uri

> Every node also has an associated URI
>   called its base URI, which is used for
>   resolving attribute values that
>   represent relative URIs into absolute
>   URIs. If an element or processing
>   instruction occurs in an external
>   entity, the base URI of that element
>   or processing instruction is the URI
>   of the external entity; otherwise, the
>   base URI is the base URI of the
>   document. The base URI of the document
>   node is the URI of the document
>   entity. The base URI for a text node,
>   a comment node, an attribute node or a
>   namespace node is the base URI of the
>   parent of the node.

So this:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('external.xml')" xml:base="http://example.org">
```

Should be resolved as

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('http://example.org/external.xml')">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the `xml:base` attribute on the document root node.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlbase/ to confirm this will do what you want.